# Unable to Connect to AWS RDS using endpoint

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, rds, amazon-rds

We have two RDS running on AWS. On is a production database and the other is a development database. Both servers were working correctly until we decided to upgrade the production server from a db.t2.micro to a db.t3.medium. After upgrading none of the connections to the database are working.

The development database is working correctly still and we can still connect correctly to that database. We have checked that the endpoint still matches the settings in the configuration files. We have checked the security settings and have it set that any ip or host can connect. Every time we try to connect we get a timeout error, so incorrect credentials don't seem to be the problem. We are able to make a connect via ip address but not using the endpoint. We have checked the settings between the two databases are they are identical except for the size and the name.

Comment: When you do an nslookup do you get the expected IP? I suggest you have someone independently check your configuration, as based on what you've said it should probably work. It will be something small and simple, but probably difficult to find.

Comment: The problem ended up being a problem with a load balancer that had been setup

Comment: Please answer your own question with a more detailed answer, and then 24 hours later accept the answer. This will help others in future.

Answer (score 0):

When restoring from snapshot, the user interface does not allow putting the database into a secondary vpc. So if you have "upgraded" by restoring from snapshot, your Rds database may be in the wrong vpc network and therefore not have a route to get to from your server.

You need to modify the vpc rds is launched into in this case.